# Procedure Parameter issue - Mysql 5.1 SQL Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.1

The following works in **MYSQL 5.5 windows**, doesn't work in **MYSQL 5.1, ubuntu lucid**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `queueup`( IN groupsize INT, OUT done INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE room INT;
    SET room = -1;
    UPDATE queue SET status = 'PLACED', assigned_room = room WHERE status = 'WAITING' ORDER BY queue_position ASC LIMIT groupsize;
END $$
```

**SQL Error 1064:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'groupsize;

Comment: the one in the LIMIT. Note, if I replace it with a hard coded number like 2, it stops complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.5 LIMIT clause can be used with variables; in your case 'groupsize' is a variable.

From [the reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) - *Within stored programs, LIMIT  parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.*

Comment: I see. So, I'll either have to rewrite the query or upgrade to 5.5 to plug a variable into LIMIT. Thanks for the help., i'll dig around the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) for 5.1 for now.

Comment: @user875933: You'll probably have to build an SQL string and execute it if you need to support 5.1: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html